# What size should a dog toilet area with weekly cleanup be?

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

We want buy a bearded collie {40–60 lbs (18–27 kg)} and want to have a designated dog toilet in the garden. What size should it be if we plan to scoop poop once per week?

Anything else we should consider for the dogs comfort and to reduce odor?

Comment: Are you asking how big the area should be if you are not going to 'scoop poop'?

Comment: Not sure. _(We just decided to have a dog next fall and are considering the consequences.)_ We will probably clean it weekly.

Comment: I have edited your question to be more clear, based on your comments. I looked and does not seem like we have this question yet.  But we do have [several related questions and answers](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet-training+dogs) that you might want to look through.

Comment: Don't do that. A border collie is a shepherd and need tons of exercise (there's no garden enough for a collie). If you are planning a toilet area, cleaned weekly, I'm betting you will not give your dog the necessary in physical areas (as I'm talking about 3-4 hours daily the first years of its life). Please consider another breed.

Comment: Don't jump in to conclusions, David. We are not at all looking for a "dog in the garden". I bed my wife alone will already spend more than 4 hours with the dog the first year, if my father in law will not "steal" it for a week.

Comment: You are right,i jumped to conclusions. So sorry. I've seen so much people looking into "logistics" before the dog, but not really thinking about its necessities

Comment: Never mind, David. It can't be said enough taking a dog is taking responsibility.